# Erro de PHP, 'exit' (T_EXIT)

Tags: php

Estou praticando um pouco de php, e quando vou executa-lo, aparece esse erro na tela do local host:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT), expecting ','
>   or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 22

eu entendo o que é erro de sintaxe, porém, eu gostaria de entender o erro.

```
[
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "users";

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($db);

if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='".$username."'AND password='".$password."'LIMIT 1";
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) == 1) {
    echo "logado";
    exit();
    } else {
    echo "dados incorretos"
        exit();
    }
    }

?>
]
```

Comment: Parece que faltou um `;` no echo antes do `exit();`, `} else {
    echo "dados incorretos"` vc está usando alguma IDE?

Comment: Sim, estou usando uma IDE, Brackets, embora ainda não indicada para server side, é só para teste mesmo.

Answer (score 6):

O erro diz que a função `exit()` não era esperada e sim um `;` ou seja o erro está na linha anterior ao `exit()`.

```
} else {
   echo "dados incorretos" <---- cade o ponto e virgula ?
exit();
```

Para evitar esse tipo de erro utilize alguma IDE como o [eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-php-developers/lunar) ou editores de texto com funcionalidades avançadas como o [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) ou [sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/).

Comment: é, me disseram que o eclipse é bem recomendado. mas por enquanto estou usando a atual para treino mesmo.

Comment: Não tem nada a ver com a IDE, mas sim o erro de sintaxe da virgula.. `+1`

Comment: Silvio, a questão é que o uso de uma IDE previne o erro, já que informa o erro, e define métodos de correção.